# Find the value on the right cell of the key

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following data table:

[image]

Is there any way to retrieve the value on the right of the "h" key (result would be 8) for example which is on the middle of the table ?

I tried VLOOKUP, HLOOKUP which seems to search on the first column / row and doesn't find it. LOOKUP alone is only searching on an unidimentional data table.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If keys are unique you can use `INDEX`:

```
=INDEX(A1:F4, SUM(ROW(A1:F4)*(H2=A1:F4)), SUM(COLUMN(A1:F4)*(H2=A1:F4))+1)
```

[image]

The formula also works in excel, just in pre-O365 versions it has to be entered as an array formula.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP("h"; {A:B;C:D;E:F}; 2; 0))
```